# How can I refer back to my object in the method I pass to getJSON as success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

In my model I'm successfully loading some JSON after which I simply dispatch an event to whoever is listening stating the JSON has loaded.

My problem was scope. I found the only way 'main' could listen successfully to the model (using jQuery's trigger method) was by prefixing the scope variable (inside the function Model (ApplicationModel) ) with a jQuery alias.

My hunch is that I may be missing a less confusing way of dealing with scope in this situation.

**main**:

```
require( [ "jquery", "models/applicationModel", "views/applicationView" ], function( $, ApplicationModel, ApplicationView ) {

var appModel = new ApplicationModel();

$( appModel ).on( "jsonLoaded", onJsonLoaded );
appModel.getJson();

function onJsonLoaded( e, data ) {
    console.log('main: onJsonLoaded', data );
}

});
```

**ApplicationModel**:

```
define( [ "jquery" ], function( $ ) {

function Model() {
    $scope = this;
};

Model.prototype.getJson = function() {
    $.getJSON( "/getTextfields", this.loadSuccess );
};

Model.prototype.loadSuccess = function( data ) {
    console.log('loadSuccess', data );
    $( $scope ).trigger( "jsonLoaded", [ data ] );
} 

return Model;
});
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$scope`?

Comment: $scope is defined in the function Model, inside the ApplicationModel above. However, the solution is below provided by Louis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your module so that it does something like this:

```
define( [ "jquery" ], function( $ ) {

function Model() {
    // Cache $(this) so that we don't call jQuery all the time.
    this.$this = $(this);
};

Model.prototype.getJson = function() {
    // Use bind so that `this` has the proper value in `loadSuccess`.
    $.getJSON( "/getTextfields", this.loadSuccess.bind(this) );
};

Model.prototype.loadSuccess = function( data ) {
    console.log('loadSuccess', data );
    // Used the cached `$this` rather than recomputing.
    this.$this.trigger( "jsonLoaded", [ data ] );
} 

return Model;

});
```

The key here is using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It creates a new function for which the value of `this` is set to the first argument passed to `bind`.

Comment: Hi Louis, thanks for your answer that's clear, works, and makes more sense than the solution I was using.